# MInimal number of faces to generate full rubik's cube state

Tags: geometry, rubiks-cube

I am wondering what's the minimal number of faces we need to know in advance to be assured of the rest of the state of the cube. For a solved cube I believe just the 3 solved faces is enough to infer the entire state of the cube. But for a scrambled cube I bet 3 faces might not be enough. I am curious to know the minimal number of faces required.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "conjecture" is not true. 3 faces are not enough. Even 4 faces are not enough:

We have to show that there exists a state of the cube such that 4 faces are solved but the remaining 2 faces aren't (since you would get two different states of the cube with the same 4 faces solved but different on the remaining 2 faces, namely the solved state and the state as described above). To get such a state, apply the following permutation: U D R2 L2 U D' R2 L2 D2. Another (qualitatively different) one would be: R2 U2 B2 R U2 D2 L U D' B2 L2 U2 B2 U D'.

5 faces is obviously enough.

Edit: As Ravi Fernando correctly observed, 5 faces is enough for a solved cube but in general it is not always enough. An example of 2 states with the same 5 faces but a different 6th face are U L' F D' L2 D F' L U' L2 U' L2 U F2 U' L2 U L2 and R2 B2 L2 D' L2 B2 R2 U F' L F' L' R U R' F U2.

Comment: Just to point out:  although you're correct that 5 faces are enough for the solved cube, it's not enough for other positions.  For example, if you don't look at the U face, the superflip looks identical to superflip + any last layer edge permutation.

Comment: Ah yes you are right, let me edit that in